How can I display backtick in stackexchange?
I may be missing something very obvious.
I want to display this Mathematica line but have an issue with the backtick in the string being interpreted as end of a Mathematica quote
g=ImportString["WsnNFaUwKUQbAMRC_xxXKCl\dQz_{bsQ\ZHYDZpPFjn{SO", "Graph6"]`
jfyi: the string codes for a graph with $24$ vertices and $132$ edges and is one of $2$ graphs that is $R(4,5)$ with that many vertices and edges - actually no such graphs exists for more than $24$ vertices.

Many thanks for the migration to the right forum!

This is addressed at length in the (highly upvoted) Meta StackExchange post  How do I escape a backtick within in-line code in Markdown?.
The gist of the Accepted Answer is to use multiple backticks as the code string delimiter.
For example your string would be displayable as (I suspect) intended by putting two backticks in front and behind:
g=ImportString["WsnNFaUwKUQbAMRC_xxXKCl\dQz_{bsQ\ZHYDZpPFj`n{SO", "Graph6"]
Note I was able to pull your original string from the Edit environment of the Question, then add a backtick before and after it.

@ hardmath Many thanks! Should I delete the question or is this ok to leave in as a special case?

I think it's good to stay.  The topic hasn't cropped here before AFAIK.  But it probably just is uncommon, and the solution is less obvious than an escape character.
